# Laravel Unauthenticated passport

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-passport

[My Postman request with dd() in Authenticate.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4BHD.png)

I am not sure where the problem is when I have it withoud dd I just get unauthenticated which doesnt makes sence since it should not go to the route(login) but I cannot continue on it since I dont know where it goes after this so I cant even trace where this happens.

[Barear Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxyUq.png)

[OAuthAcessTokens In DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d4LB.png)

[Middleware Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJjZI.png)

[RouteMiddleware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zilsO.png)

[Authenticate.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0u6h.png)
[Api.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYCa7.png)

[Auth service provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeHcx.png)

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login');
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Well i think you need to retrieve a token first, it seems you added the credentials to the body, you should have a route like `api/oauth/token` or `api/v1/oauth/token`. It will give you an access_token field that you need to put in the Authorization header

Comment: I have that token already let me put that also into question

Answer (score 0):

can you attach the image of your Authenticate.php file?

Comment: Okay I updated it if you need more just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

[image: have you added this ?]
Try this if you haven't added yet.

Comment: Yeah I have that already but funny thing when I dont add it its blank completly when I do add it I get auth failed.